# Symfony application shows directory listing when using https

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting, apache2.4

Normal VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/current/web
ServerAdmin me@app.foobar
ServerName app.foobar
ServerAlias www.app.foobar
<Directory /var/www/html/app/current/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All      

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !HTTP/1.1$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" 
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

HTTPS VHOST:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>    
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/current/web
ServerName app.foobar
ServerAdmin me@app.foobar
<Directory /var/www/html/app/current/web>
AllowOverride None
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
<IfModule mod_rewrite> 
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !HTTP/1.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule> 
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCertificateFile /ssl/app.foobar/app.foobar.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/app.foobar/app.foobar.key
SSLCACertificateFile /ssl/app.foobar/app.foobar.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

As the title says when I use regular port 80 the urls are rewritten to use app.php but when I try to use https port 443 I get a directory listing instead. How do I get the url rewritten with https like it does with http?

Comment: I've just been digging through the apache mod_rewrite documentation and found the `FallbackResource` directive. This seems to work. But why is this not in the Symfony documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the `FallbackResource` directive available in Apache 2.2.16+.

In the official Symfony docs this directive is not used to remain backwards compatible with older version of Apache. Discussion is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/symfony2/B20W2wBSsiY/ngaMNKLOE5YJ).

Code example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/app/current/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All      

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        FallbackResource /app.php
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```